# Why does a redux-saga use put method instead of dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

The demonstration example in the [README](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) file uses a function called `put()` instead of `dispatch()` in the worker saga.

```
...

// worker Saga: will be fired on USER_FETCH_REQUESTED actions
function* fetchUser(action) {
   try {
      const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId);
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", user: user});
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}

...
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Redux-Sagas is based on [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). Whenever you call one of these, it gets executed until it reaches a **`yield`**. This, besides allowing you to perform async actions by waiting for promises, has a bunch of advantages when it comes to testing for example.

Esentially, mocking is what is trying to be avoided here when you are testing. In order to do so, a declarative approach is followed. The point is that **you don't dispatch (nor really do anything), the middleware does**. You only provide this middleware with objects called **Effects**. So, what the **put** will do is **to create an Effect object that the middleware will "read". Then, it will dispatch the action and use `next(result)`** (with `result` being the result of whatever the Effect told the middleware to do)  **to go to the next yield and get the next Effect**. You can read more about it [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DispatchingActions.html).

Remember that the main advantages of redux-sagas when compared to redux-thunk [appear when testing comes in](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/Effect.html). **Being able to just declare which Effect will be returned by each put, call...** [and then just iterating from yield to yield](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html) instead of having to mock API calls or dispatches is a major selling point for redux-sagas. You probably need to read and practise a little bit more before you get the concept completely but I hope my explanation solves your doubt.